# Forge viewer: 3D markups with text

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We're trying to display markups in a specific location (upper right) on top of each object in our 3D model. We would also want to render text on the 3D markups. Is this possible? If it is, we will put a post processing shader on top of it so it doesn't hide underneath something else in the model as we navigate around.

Option 2:
In 2D, either in Forge or in HTML, this would be images with text on top, during every frame the positions of these images+text will have to be updated to match the 2D positions of the 3D objects, this could work but it might lag, and this is why we'd prefer to use the 3D option - if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my latest [PointCloud Markup demo](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a361b2b58144b5ed2936ddf) for an example of a custom shader using a dynamic texture: [High-Performance 3D markups with PointCloud in the Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/high-performance-3d-markups-pointcloud-forge-viewer).

You could use a similar approach to generate a texture that contains a label ...

[image]

```
createShader (options) {

  // Vertex Shader code
  const vertexShader = options.vertexShader || `
      attribute float pointSize;
      attribute vec4 color;
      varying vec4 vColor;
      void main() {
        vec4 vPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vPosition;
        gl_PointSize = pointSize;
        vColor = color;
      }
    `

  // Fragment Shader code
  const fragmentShader = options.fragmentShader || `
      uniform sampler2D texture;
      varying vec4 vColor;
      void main() {
        vec4 tex = texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
        if (tex.a < 0.2) discard;
        if (vColor.a == 0.0) {
          gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex.g, tex.b, tex.a);
        } else {
          gl_FragColor = vColor;
        }
      }
    `

  const tex = options.texture || defaultTex

  // Shader material parameters
  const shaderParams = options.shaderParams || {
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      depthWrite: false,
      depthTest: false,
      fragmentShader,
      vertexShader,
      opacity: 0.5,
      attributes: {
        pointSize: {
          type: 'f',
          value: []
        },
        color: {
          type: 'v4',
          value: []
        }
      },
      uniforms: {
        texture: {
          value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tex),
          type: 't'
        }
      }
    }

  // creates shader material
  const material =
    new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
      shaderParams)

  const generateTexture = (size, radius) => {

    const pixels = []

    for (let u = 0; u < size; ++u) {

      for (let v = 0; v < size ; ++v) {

        const dist = Math.sqrt(
          (u/size - 0.5) * (u/size - 0.5) +
          (v/size - 0.5) * (v/size - 0.5))

        if (dist < 0.1) {

          pixels.push(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff)

        } else if (dist < (radius - 0.05)) {

          pixels.push(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)

        } else if (dist < radius) {

          pixels.push(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff)

        } else {

          pixels.push(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
        }
      }
    }

    const dataTexture = new THREE.DataTexture (
      Uint8Array.from (pixels),
      size, size,
      THREE.RGBAFormat,
      THREE.UnsignedByteType,
      THREE.UVMapping
    )

    dataTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter
    dataTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter // THREE.NearestFilter
    dataTexture.needsUpdate = true

    return dataTexture
  }

  const stopwatch = new Stopwatch()

  let radius = 0.0

  return {
    setTexture: (tex) => {

      const {texture} = shaderParams.uniforms

      texture.value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tex)

      texture.needsUpdate = true

    },
    update: () => {

      const dt = stopwatch.getElapsedMs() * 0.001

      radius += dt * 0.25

      radius = radius > 0.5 ? 0.0 : radius

      const {texture} = shaderParams.uniforms

      texture.value = generateTexture(96, radius)

      texture.needsUpdate = true

    },
    material
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the update.

With it, we can determine what symbol (pixels) should be shown per frame.

So with this, we can do any animation, but more importantly, we can draw any symbol/text imaginable, so a circle with a number in it is now possible.

Downside is only that it has to be programmed per pixel, so you can't just say: draw text "50" with fontsize 20px and color white centered. Instead, you have to say: pixel 1,1 transparent, pixel 1,2 white, etc. It might take some time to make text rendering possible with it. 

It's not undoable now though, that's the important thing.

Comment: Power comes with responsibilities... shaders are very powerful but it's low level so yes you would need to handle this on your side. The other workaround is to use 2D DOM overlay as you mentioned, where you can easily display text along with svg graphics but performances will be nowhere near what you can get with shaders, especially if you plan to display a large number of markups.